# How to fix git error "It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory"?

Tags: git

I am trying to test something with git/gitlab, but I get the error

```
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
    git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
    rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

when I try to run

```
git rebase continue
```

on a rebase with a conflict. I already removed and git cloned the whole repository, removed all branches and all merge requests, but this strange `rebase-apply directory` error keeps popping up. Also even after removing that folder

```
rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
```

then `git rebase` gives an error

```
fatal: invalid upstream 'continue'
```

What is going on? How to remove this error once and for all?

As this is a testrepo, EVERYTHING can be removed/deleted. But how to get rid of this annoying error?

Comment: it should be `git rebase --continue`. U missed the '--'. `git rebase continue`  without -- will look for `continue` branch.

Comment: to abort a rebasing use git rebase --abort

Comment: Yes, I miss the dashes. Sorry, I was trying to recreate a situation and repeated the whole workflow like 4 times...

Comment: Would a `rebase --quit` be more successful?

Comment: `--quit` worked for me but I was looking for a fix for being in a rebase state without rebasing, so not related to the question of this post.

Answer (score -2):

The error msg shows exactly what it is.

Type

> git status

, and you know the branch is in rebasing.

Try

> git rebase --abort

on your current branch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).